# How to integrate Lua to Cocos2d-X for Windows and Android?

Tags: android, c++, lua, cocos2d-x

I already created my project for Windows and Android with create_project script as C++ project.

I want to integrate Lua to my project, but I don't know how to do this.

On Windows project can I just add include directory to Lua directory and add lua5.1.lib like normal Windows application?

On Android project I have no idea how to integrate Lua to it.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not generate a Lua project directly, using create_project tool with language=lua? Or you can generate a new Lua project and copy the project settings into your existing C++ projects.

Comment: I created a project with language = lua. When I export android project to eclipse it seems like the project doesn't know about a code from cocos2d.h, and I looked at the android.mk it's quite different from a project that I created with language = C++. Can you give me more detail of copying project settings from lua project to C++ project. Thank you.